# Entering in more characters than a function parameter tables SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have this code snippet I'm playing with (forgive the generic names):

```
create function GetList
(@d1 varchar(3), @d2 varchar(3), @d3 varchar(3))
returns table
as
return
with List
as
(
    select x.pattern
        from (values (@d1), (@d2), (@d3)) as x(pattern)
)
select * from list
```

This is eventually going to be a user-supplied list which they will use to query something else out, but playing around with this made me curious.  If I were to run

`select * from GetList('1111111','222','333')`

I will get the same results as if I only entered in 3 characters for each.  Since I limited the varchar parameter to characters, are the others completely ignored?  Is there any potential nastiness that can happen if I have a varchar parameter that is 'overflowed' like this (other than the loss of data at the end of the string, of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other characters totally ignored since you limited the parameter to a length of 3.

The only issue that you could have is if you actually wanted to return the characters that are over the length of 3.

For example, you pass in `1234567` and you actually want the whole value, you will only get `123`.

If you are limiting the input parameter to 3, then there would be no reason to try and pass in a longer value. If there is a chance that you will pass in longer values, then you should increase the length of the parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know if there was some commonly-exploited overflow error that might happen.  The reason why I did this was the 'never underestimate the user' type situation :).  Plus, I was kind of curious what would happen.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie One thing you can do if you have user inputted values, if make sure they can only enter 3 character.  You can use substring, etc to correct the length.

Comment: Unless you don't care about the rest and simply allow it to truncate it to 3